# How can I convert EV3 Lab code to the new EV3 Classroom?

Tags: ev3, ev3-g

I have been running a robotics club at our local school for ~10 years, and just starting up again after covid. We are still using all our old EV3 kits, which work fine, but now have new laptops running the new (Scratch-like) EV3 Classroom coding environment. But the robot instructions [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593275323) are all based on the old system (EV3 Labs). Is there a way to convert the old block-based code to the current Scratch-based code?